# Django Like mechanism. Database performance question

Tags: python, django, database, performance, many-to-many

I have CustomUser model and Post model. I consider adding a lightweight like mechanism to the posts.

What comes to my mind is defining a Like model in such fashion to connect the models to each other:

```
class LikeFeedback(models.Model):
   likingUser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
   post_liked = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

But this design produces a new row in the database with each like.

---

Another option is to define CustomUser and Post models in a way that:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   ... 
   users_liked = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)

class CustomUser(models.Model):
   ... 
   posts_liked = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

I am not sure if this approach creates a new row or uses a different indexing mechanism, but it looks tidier.

In terms of DB performance what approach is the fastest? Do I need to define the ManyToMany connection in both models to speed up DB processes? Because 15 posts are to be displayed on the webpage at once and and with every post it is necessary to check if the visitor already liked the note. Also, with each like and takeback a write operation is to be performed on the DB.

Comment: Just use *one* `ManyToManyField` from the `Post` to the user (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure if this approach creates a new row or uses a different indexing mechanism, but it looks tidier.

A `ManyToManyField` will create an *extra* table called a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) with `ForeignKey`s to the model where you define the `ManyToManyField`, and the model that you target with the `ManyToManyField`.

You furthermore only need *one* `ManyToManyField`, otherwise you make two relations that act indepdently. You thus model this as:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    # ... 
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='liked_posts'
    )

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    # ... 
    # no ManyToManyField to Post
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Your approach looks fast at determining the Users who liked a specific post. But is it still fast if I was to get all the Posts a specific user liked? Btw `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a cool trick for modulity.

Comment: @Xfce4: yes, since on the two `ForeignKey`s, the database will set an index, so you can query in *both* directions.

Comment: So the indexing is done for both sides. Cool fact. I was considering if I should store the liking Users and liked Posts as a string (i.e. in JSON format) but indexing would make searching much faster I suppose. Thanks a lot for your time and the clear info.